# Share records with a particular user only.

Tags: roles, public-group

I may case their are 2 CEO (A, B) and 2 COO (C, D). I want to share record of A only to C and B only to D. I have set the object to private and create 2 group. 1st group with (A and C), 2nd group with (B and D). But If I create a sharing rule to share all the records of CEO with 1st group, in this case how can I select of which CEO - A or B. Please guide me with better way to achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend setting up roles in your role hierarchy , where C is the subordinate to A and D is subordinate to B. You then create sharing rules that all records owned by A and Subordinates be shared to all members of A and their subordinates and you apply the same thing for B and D.

Hope it helps

Comment: hi @mihai thanks but I may case both I have 2 CEO (A, B) and 2 COO (C, D) for a single company. So how can I have different roles for same kind of people.

Comment: Are you saying that one person might perform the same role CEO and COO ?

Comment: No I mean 1 role for 2 users (A and B) - but A only want to share records with C not with D. In this case you have mention that setting up roles in your role hierarchy. But if I set up role the A and B will hold the same role as CEO and C and D will have role as COO. Then role COO will be subordinate to CEO. Here how can we assign that C is subordinate to A, vice versa. So that in my public group I can share the records of A only to C not with D.

Comment: Have a look at this video: http://salesforce.vidyard.com/watch/CwsXBBl9WsU9qkVRytOx0A . This is what I mean by role hierarchy. A group is similar to roles, but it mimics a flat organisation.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a trigger for that, you can use trigger for insert share record detail in share object related to your object...

internally all sharing records stores in a share object.. here is a snap for Account share object...
[image]

and you can code for that like...

```
 AccountShare shareRec=new AccountShare();
     shareRec.AccessLevel='Read';
     shareRec.ParentId=Acc.id;
     shareRec.UserOrGroupId=sharingWithUserIds;
   insert shareRec;
```

May this exaple would be helpful..... Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of having a "sharing rule to share all the records of CEO with 1st group" , create a sharing rule to share records of 1st public group to itself. Consider group "Test". Your sharing rule will be like:

Share records of group: Test

Share records with group : Test

This will ensure that you are sharing records of user A with C only.

Hope this helps you.

Thanks!